# Sorting of list in Python by integer in descending order

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a Python list created with fuzzywuzzy

```
result=[(fuzz.WRatio(n, n2),n2,sdf.index[x],bdf.index[y])
                    for y, n2 in enumerate(Col2['name']) if fuzz.WRatio(n, n2)>70 and len(n2) >= 2]
    print('Result: {}'.format(result))
```

which will produce the following result:

```
String to compare to raw data: ABC
Result: [(90, u'ABC COMPANY', 21636, 100079), (86, u'ABC COMPANY CO', 21636, 72933), (86, u'ABC (M) SDN BHD', 21636, 92592), (95, u'ABC PTE LTD.', 21636, 171968)]
```

I would like to be able to sort the whole list by the first digit of each array in descending order. I have tried using

```
result.sort()
```

which doesn't sort the list in descending order, any idea?

Comment: Using a lambda function as key for sort should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from operator import itemgetter

values = [(90, u'ABC COMPANY', 21636, 100079), (86, u'ABC COMPANY CO', 21636, 72933), (86, u'ABC (M) SDN BHD', 21636, 92592), (95, u'ABC PTE LTD.', 21636, 171968)]
values.sort(key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
print(values)
```

**Output**

```
[(95, 'ABC PTE LTD.', 21636, 171968), (90, 'ABC COMPANY', 21636, 100079), (86, 'ABC COMPANY CO', 21636, 72933), (86, 'ABC (M) SDN BHD', 21636, 92592)]
```

One alternative is to use a lambda function as key:

```
values.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`list.sort()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/__builtin__.list.sort) has a `reverse` kwarg. Use it